# Tailwind - content in grid overflows even when the height of the component is set to h-full

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using a grid to layout some components, The issue is below:
[The content that I want to fit in the grid overflows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf11w.png), ideally I want it to look something like this:
[Ideal solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx6MA.png) where the content fits nicely and the content of each tab is the only thing that can be scrolled through.
Currently - when there is content in the tab that would overflow, the height of the component content exceeds that of the grid container - like the images (the border colours are there just for my visualisation)

This is my current work:
Patient Notes:

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import PatientNotesDropDown from '../misc/PatientNotesDropDown'
import { Tabs, Tab } from '../misc/Tabs'

const PatientNotes = () => {
  return (
    <div className='h-full text-black flex flex-col justify-between '>
        <div className='flex flex-col justify-start rounded-xl border-2 border-zinc-400 backdrop-blur-sm h-full'>
            <div className='flex justify-center px-4 pt-2 pb-4 items-center'>
                <div className='tracking-widest text-lg'>
                    <p>PATIENT NOTES</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div className='border-2 h-full border-orange-500 px-2 pb-2 grid'>
                <Tabs >
                    <Tab label="MEDICAL">
                        <div className="h-full justify-between px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center border-black border-2'>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">PAST MEDICAL HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </Tab>

                    <Tab label="SURGICAL">
                        <div className="px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">PAST SURGICAL HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </Tab>



                    <Tab label="FAMILY">
                        <div className="px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">FAMILY HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            <div className='h-full overflow-auto'>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">IMMEDIATE FAMILY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">SECONDARY FAMILY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">TERTIARY FAMILY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">CHILDREN</h2>
                                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>


                    <Tab label="SOCIAL">
                        <div className="px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">SOCIAL HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            <div className='h-full overflow-auto'>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">HOUSING</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">OCCUPATION</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">FITNESS</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">SMOKING, ALCOHOL AND ILLICIT SUBSTANCES</h2>
                                     
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>


                    <Tab label="PHYSC">
                        <div className="flex flex-col justify-between h-full px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='border-2 border-black flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">PSYCHIATRIC HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            <div className='overflow-auto border-2 border-black '>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">MENTAL STATE EXAMINATION</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">PREVIOUS ADMISSIONS</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">FORENSIC HISTORY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">RISKS</h2>
                                     
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
                </div>

            
        
        </div>
        
        <h2 className='text-center tracking-widest font-medium text-xs pt-1'>PATIENT NOTES</h2>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default PatientNotes
```

Tabs:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Tabs = ({ children, width }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(children[0].props.label);

  const handleClick = (e, newActiveTab) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setActiveTab(newActiveTab);
  };

  return (
    <div className="mx-2 border-red-500 border-2 place-self-center w-full flex flex-col min-h-0 h-full">
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        {children.map(child => (
          <button
            key={child.props.label}
            className={`${
              activeTab === child.props.label ? 'border-l-[1px] border-t-[1px] border-r-[1px] rounded-t-lg border-b-[1px] border-b-gray-50 ' : 'border-l-[1px] border-t-[1px] border-r-[1px] rounded-t-lg'
            } text-center text-gray-700 font-base py-1 border-zinc-500 text-[10px]  tracking-widest -mb-[1px] w-full ml-1 mr-1`}
            onClick={e => handleClick(e, child.props.label)}
          >
            {child.props.label}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="py-2 border-zinc-500 border-[5px] min-h-0 ml-1 mr-1 rounded-b-lg mb-2 h-full">
        {children.map(child => {
          if (child.props.label === activeTab) {
            return <div key={child.props.label} className='min-h-0 h-full border-4 border-green-500'>{child.props.children}</div>;
          }
          return null;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Tab = ({ label, children }) => {
  return (
    <div label={label} className="hidden">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export { Tabs, Tab };
```

My grid:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-12 grid-rows-10 gap-3 p-3 h-screen place-items-stretch ">
      <div className="col-span-12 bg-gray-200">1</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-5 row-start-2 bg-gray-200"><LastVisitedPatient /></div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-3 col-start-1 row-start-7 bg-gray-200"><Bloods /></div>
      <div className="col-span-12 col-start-1 row-start-10 bg-gray-200">6</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-2 bg-gray-200">7</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-4 bg-gray-200">8</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-4 col-start-10 row-start-6 h-full bg-gray-200">9</div>
      <div className="col-span-6 row-span-8 col-start-4 row-start-2 bg-gray-200 w-full min-h-0"><PatientNotes /></div>
    </div>
```